# Change of Variable issue

Tags: calculus

I got across the integral
$$\int_{\omega} \nabla y(x) \mathrm{d}x$$ $$y\colon \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$$
It would be better to perform the integration over the domain $\Omega$, the two domains being related by a transformation $Y\colon\omega \to \Omega$.
Using the change of variable rule I wrote
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla y(Y(x)) \det\nabla Y \mathrm{d}x $$ which should equal,using the chain rule and indicating partial derivatives with the pedix notation
$$\int_{\Omega} y_{Y} Y_{x} \det\nabla Y \mathrm{d}x $$
I verified by comparison to a paper that my calculation is wrong (the term $Y_{x}$ is not present), but I can not understand why. 
Thank you ever so much for any help.

Comment: Give us some numbers to work with... What is $y(x)$, what are $\omega$ and $\Omega$?

Comment: I think you change variables *after* computing derivatives. I mean, you want to integrate the function $u=\nabla y$. Now you apply the change-of-variable theorem with $Y$ and $u$, and you get $\int_\Omega u(Y(x)) |\det Y'(x)|\, dx$.

Comment: To 5xum, the problem is of a physical nature, y(x) is a deformation gradient, $\omega$ is a cracked domain and $\Omega$ is a reference domain, the map $Y$ is used to avoid issues with the variability of the cracked domain as the crack progresses, I will post the link of the paper in question if you are interested, thanks

Comment: Also, $\nabla y$ is a function on $\omega$ shouldn't it be transformed by $Y^{-1}$ as it stands?

Comment: to Siminore, I understand what you say but it seems equivalent to me,  your conclusive expression  ∫Ωu(Y(x))|detY′(x)| is it not the same as I obtain, once you compute the gradient of the composite function in the integrand? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Buco Let me explain, since this is a typical source of trouble. Let $y(x)=\sin x$ and $Y(x)=e^x$. What is $\nabla y(Y(x))$? Is this the derivative of $x \mapsto \sin e^x$ or just $\cos e^x$? In your example, my opinion is that $\nabla y(Y(x))= \left( \nabla y \right) \circ Y$.

Comment: I see, I completely overlooked this detail. I can only then say, thank you, grazie!